# Sql query creation for combines two tables and shuffling results

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create an SQL query that selects 
 the pictures of females in my database then randomise the pictures after that select pictures of  males than randomise them .  For instance there are 40 pictures of girls and 60 pictures of boys . I want that 1st 40 pictures of girls are selected (shuffled and then the remaining pictures of boys are selected (shuffled)

Hope i am clear . I have two tables "userID" field is the one that links both the tables.

> User table (age , UserID , gender) | Picture table ( UserID ,
>   numberoflikes , picure_location)

Is there anyway I could generate this query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT picure_location
FROM Picture
  INNER JOIN User ON Picture.UserID=User.UserID
ORDER BY gender,RAND()
```

You might need `ORDER BY GENDER DESC, RAND()` depending on how you represent the gender.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
SET @num1=0, @num2=0;
SELECT t1.*, p1.picturelocation,t2.*, p2.picturelocation 
FROM (
    SELECT UserID,gender, @num1:=@num1+1 AS num
    FROM UserTable WHERE gender='Female'
) AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserID,gender, @num2:=@num2+1 AS num
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM UserTable WHERE gender='Male'
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 40
    ) AS t
) AS t2
ON t1.num = t2.num 
INNER JOIN PictureTable p1 on t1.userid=p1.userid 
INNER JOIN PictureTable p2 on t2.userid=p2.userid;
```